# If I make a hotspot and connect my mobile to my laptop, can an ISP detect it?

Tags: networking, internet, security, hot-spot, wireless-access-point

I am running a hotspot using the `create_ap` bash script on Ubuntu. Is there any way for an ISP to detect the devices connected to a computer on which a hotspot is made?

Comment: There is a security-specific Stack Exchange site https://security.stackexchange.com where you will likely find a higher quality answer. If you would expand on why you're asking and note in a comment here you would welcome the post being moved there, I am sure you will get a much more comprehensive answer.

Comment: If its answers mention Ubuntu software, then this question is not off topic at Ask Ubuntu either.

Comment: @karel by that logic Mint questions will be on-topic as long as answers mention Ubuntu software. Sina M, which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: You are using an account and password to connect to their systems. So yes, they can and they do. ISP log every activity. Even a VPN is not safe in that regards: they know you use a VPN, just can't see what you visit directly (they would need the security key from the vpn company)

Answer (score 3):

The ISP can't identify your devies *directly*, but it can detect them in several ways analyzing your traffic. For example, [most of the browsers have a unique fingerprint](https://wiki.mozilla.org/index.php?title=Fingerprinting) that can be used to track it.

As far as I know, there is no infallible way to prevent your ISP from detecting your devices; still, there are some ways you can prevent it from reading the content your traffic, such as VPNs or [Tor Browser](https://www.torproject.org/). Those methods are not completely "anonymous" (for example, P2P connections can be identified without knowing their content) but they help you to hide a lot of information that are useful to track your online activity. Note that the ISP and whoever is able to intercept your traffic would find out that you are hiding them.

Anyway, it's worth noting that in most cases your ISP can't log nor analyze your internet activity without your consent, especially if you live in the EU.

---

I hope that my answer will be useful. If you provide some more information about why you are interested on the topic I might be able to give you a more detailed answer.

Comment: If i spoof my address so my devices have same mac and also connect my phone with a vpn or tor, is it still obvious and detectable

Comment: As said in other comments, multiple devices pretending to have the same MAC address are most likely to create problems than solving them. Supposing it works, it wouldn't change much anyway. Also, some ISP might block "strange" connections like VPN and TOR.

Answer (score 2):

They can sure see you're running a hotspot, and most ISPs which charge extra for it  (cellphone companies) automatically block it unless you are paying for that service. They could also look at the http: traffic and see [what kind of OS and browsers are in use](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent), to make an educated guess about the type and number of systems using it.

Comment: How can they see? Ip or mac address?

Comment: Click on link in my answer which explains how.

Comment: @SinaM how about your user account and password :P

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they can still detect it.  They will be able to see the multiple MAC addresses.  If you want to hide the number of machines accessing the internet from your router, you need to set up a SOCKS proxy server on your computer.  The machines you want to hide will not recognize each other like they would on a LAN (most hotspot software creates an intranet between all connected devices), but they will be hidden.

Comment: What if I spoof my device mac address so both devices have same mac?

Comment: That would cause network problems.  If two devices both have the same MAC address, that would either lead to a situation where both devices receive the packets destined for their shared MAC address, or a situation where the first device will receive all the packets and the second device won't receive any packets.  It probably depends on the router/hotspot driver.  My bet is that the hotspot/router would not let the second device join the network with a duplicate MAC address in the first place though.

Comment: You are right, they don't, but i have Increased the TTL for the connected device (here my mobile) using this iptables -w -t mangle -I PREROUTING -i ap0 -j TTL --ttl-inc 2 and after that they can not block it and it works fine

Comment: There won't be multiple MAC addresses if using NATed.  You shouldn't do spoofing.